# Folder is recognized as file

Tags: windows-7

On my Windows 7 pc I have/had this folder called "stackexchange.christianity".

Now the system says it is a file (*right click -> Properties* states: **Type of file: CHRISTIANITY File (.christianity)**; also it does not have the folder icon, but the "blank", don't-know-how-to-open-this icon).

I have found at least another folder whith a similar name ("stil.hp6") which is correctly recognised as a folder and I can open it.

Both were stored on an external hard drive.

Can I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the period with a legal character.

There is no guarantee any OS/File System will interpret a period in a folder name correctly. As a folder is simply a special file type, it can easily be misinterpreted as a file.

Much, much more at [MS KB: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Not helpful.I only get _If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable. Are you sure you want to change it?_ but the problem isn't solved.

Comment: You might need to run a disk/file checker over the drive afterwards, or recover from a backup. The real 'fix' would have been to not use an illegal character in a folder name.

Answer (score -2):

Since files are the ones having extention  unlike folders , windows considers the part after the  dot(.)  as the extention name.

This is why even if ur stackexchange.christianity is a folder, it would still think that as a file with 'stackexchange.com'  as it's name and "Christianity' as its extention.

This doesn't happen so in Linux unlike windows.
However there might be cases it would still consider the folder as folder even of it has dot.